# Calculating aggregate values in a pandas dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a Pandas DataFrame with multiple columns.

```py
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
print(df)

first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux  \
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one   
A      -0.093829 -0.159939 -0.386961 -0.367417  0.625646  1.286186  0.429855   
B       0.440266  0.345161  1.798363 -1.265215  0.204303 -1.492993 -1.714360   
C       0.689076 -1.211060 -0.265888  0.769467 -0.706941  0.086907 -0.892892 

first             
second       two  
A      -1.006210  
B      -0.275578  
C      -0.563757
```

I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation, of each column, grouping by the upper column. Once I have calculated the mean and standard deviation I want to double the columns in the lower level, adding to the column name the information related to the statistical operation (mean or standard deviation) as "column name" + "_" + "std/mean".

```py
group_cols = df.groupby(df.columns.get_level_values('first'), axis=1)
list_stat_dfs = []
for key, group in group_cols:
    group_descr = group.describe().loc[['mean', 'std'], :]  # Get mean and std from single site
    group_descr.loc[:, (key, 'stats')] = group_descr.index
    group_descr.loc[:, (key, 'first')] = key
    group_descr.columns = group_descr.columns.droplevel(0)  # Remove upper level column (site_name)
    group_descr = group_descr.pivot(columns='stats', index='first')  # Rows to columns
    col_prod = list(product(group_descr.columns.levels[0], group_descr.columns.levels[1]))
    cols = ['_'.join((col[0], col[1])) for col in col_prod]
    group_descr.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(([key], cols))  # From multiple columns to single column
    group_descr.reset_index(inplace=True)
    list_stat_dfs.append(group_descr)

group_descr = pd.concat(list_stat_dfs, axis=1)
print(group_descr)

first       bar                              first       baz            \
         one_mean   one_std  two_mean  two_std        one_mean   one_std   
0   bar  0.507185  1.799053 -0.249692  1.41507   baz -0.147664  0.595927  

                     first       foo                               first  \
   two_mean   two_std        one_mean   one_std  two_mean   two_std         
0  0.160018  1.405113   foo -0.433644  1.245972  0.254995  0.846983   qux 

        qux                                
   one_mean   one_std  two_mean   two_std  
0  0.667629  0.315417 -0.757989  0.683273
```

As you can see, I have been able to manage it with a for loop and some line of code. Can someone do the same thing in a more optimized way. I am quite sure that with Pandas, the same thing can be done with few lines of code.

Comment: Can you explain the expected output? Where does the A, B and C go?

Comment: The expected output is the second table in my question (the one in the end). A, B and C are pivoted, so they disappear. See the line of code group_descr = group_descr.pivot(columns='stats', index='first')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need get `mean` and `std` of `df`, then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

np.random.seed(1000)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
print(df)
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux  \
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one   
A      -0.804458  0.320932 -0.025483  0.644324 -0.300797  0.389475 -0.107437   
B       0.595036 -0.464668  0.667281 -0.806116 -1.196070 -0.405960 -0.182377   
C      -0.138422  0.705692  1.271795 -0.986747 -0.334835 -0.099482  0.407192   

first             
second       two  
A      -0.479983  
B       0.103193  
C       0.919388  

df = pd.concat([df.mean(), df.std()], keys=('mean','std')).unstack(1)
df.index =  [[0] * len(df.index), ['_'.join((col[1], col[0])) for col in df.index]]
df = df.unstack()
print (df)
first       bar                                     baz                      \
       one_mean   one_std  two_mean   two_std  one_mean   one_std  two_mean   
0     -0.115948  0.700018  0.187319  0.596511  0.637865  0.649139 -0.382846   

first                 foo                                     qux           \
        two_std  one_mean   one_std  two_mean   two_std  one_mean  one_std   
0      0.894129 -0.610567  0.507346 -0.038656  0.401191  0.039126  0.32095   

first                      
       two_mean   two_std  
0      0.180866  0.702911
```

Comment: I test it with your solution, numbers are correct, only in values are mixed upper column names. Do you need it?

Comment: No, that's fine ... I'm not interested in the order of the upper columns ... you're solution works really well ... actually even better than expected, since it removes the repeated lower column (column "first" in my example)

Comment: Super, glad can help you.